Timeline and expectations of New Azure Access
I work for a company that hosts our remote connection to our program through Azure. This allows our customers to access our Desktop-style application from anywhere using the Remote Desktop app. With the change announced that the Remote Desktop app is no longer being updated, and the Azure program being slated to not be used on that app in the future, we are researching the use of the Windows App for our customers. I have some questions regarding this, which I would like to discuss with someone if possible. I have them listed in brief detail below.

What is the timeline for the move from RD to Windows App?
will this require those who currently use RD to uninstall and then install the Windows app, or can they use it still?
Will this affect Windows and Mac end-users?
Will there be a hard shut off soon, or a slow grandfathering process, or something in between?

We would like to be prepared to prevent any issues with program access to our customer base, which spans all over the world. The more prepared we can be, the better this transition will be for us and our growing customer base.
I have researched online and have not found many articles or posts about my questions above. I have mostly found the following pop-message on a few pages on Microsoft support:
*"We're no longer updating the Remote Desktop app for Windows with new features and support for Azure Virtual Desktop will be removed in the future.
For the best Azure Virtual Desktop experience that includes the latest features and updates, we recommend you download the Windows Desktop client instead."*
The above was copied from the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windows
